# If $T=15.04-.000649h$ and $P=101.29+\left(\frac{T+273.1}{288.08}\right)^{5.256}$, compute $dP/dh$ at $h=3000$

Tags: calculus

I just need help getting started with this problem.

> The atmospheric temperature $T$ (Celsius) is given by $$T=15.04-.000649h$$ where $h$ is the altitude (meters) and $0 \leq h \leq 11,000$. The pressure $P$ (kilopascals) is given by $$P= 101.29 + \left(\frac{T+273.1}{288.08}\right)^{5.256}$$ Use the chain rule to compute $$\left.\frac{dP}{dh}\right\lvert_{h=3000}$$

I'm not allowed to compute using the composition formula. Any help with how to get started would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using the chain rule, we have that $\frac{dP}{dh}=\frac{dP}{dT} \cdot \frac{dT}{dh}$.

Comment: You say:"I'm not allowed to compute using the composition formula" - What is the "composition formula"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P= 101.29 + \left(\frac{T+273.1}{288.08}\right)^{5.256}, \>\>\>\>\>T=15.04-.000649h$$

Apply the chain rule,

$$\frac{dP}{dT} =5.256 \left(\frac{T+273.1}{288.08}\right)^{5.256-1}\frac{1}{288.08},\>\>\>\>\>\frac{dT}{dh}=-0.000649$$

For $h=3000$,

$$T=15.04-.000649\times 3000=13.093$$
$$\frac{dP}{dT} =5.256 \left(\frac{13.093+273.1}{288.08}\right)^{4.256}\frac{1}{288.08}=0.017742$$
Together,

$$\frac{dP}{dh}=\frac{dP}{dT}\frac{dT}{dh} =0.017742\times (-0.000649)=-0.00001151$$